# ¿Cómo se lee una Date por scanner?

Tags: java

Tengo otro problemilla en mi programa.

el problema es en las siguientes partes del código:

```
Track track1 = new Track(1111, Date?? , "MesuraX", "Pacient1", 12);
```

( problema es que no sé como poner algun valor para que DATE no me de error... )

Y luego en esta otra parte:

```
System.out.println("Data??");
date = lector.next();
track1.setDataTrack(date);
```

¿Cómo se lee una Date por scanner?

**FINAL**

No se puede leer scanner la solución es esta:

```
System.out.println("Data??");
String fechaComoTexto = lector.nextLine();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
date = sdf.parse(fechaComoTexto);
track1.setDataTrack(date);
```

Comment: Hola Montse, en lugar de colocar todo el código, coloca sólo la parte con la que tengas el problema, pero incluyendo todo lo necesario para reproducir el error. Por favor lee: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ya lo he puesto! está abajo! las dos partes del error! ;)

Comment: Luego de toda una pared de código (...) se ve que tu problema está en las últimas tres líneas del final

Comment: si.. pongo todo el código por que creo que es mejor entender de donde viene el problema.

Igualmente si creéis que puede estar mejor podéis editarlo.

Comment: Pues no, no es necesario. Solo es necesario colocar la parte problemática, a menos que todo el resto de código se necesite para entender el problema (lo cual en este caso no aplica).

Comment: Edito! Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se puede leer un `Date` a través de un `Scanner`. Lo que puedes hacer es leer una cadena de texto `String` y convertir esta cadena a un objeto `Date`. Lo puedes hacer utilizando la clase `SimpleDateFormat` (se omite el manejo de excepciones en el código para facilitar su lectura y comprensión):

```
String fechaComoTexto = lector.nextLine();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date fecha = sdf.parse(fechaComoTexto);
```

Comment: voy a probarlo!

Comment: Pero sigo con el siguiente problema:

 Track track1 = new Track(1111, Date?? , "MesuraX", "Pacient1", 12);

que pongo donde DATE??

Comment: ¿Has intentado utilizar `new Track(1111, fecha, ...)` donde `fecha` es la variable de ejemplo en el código que he escrito en la respuesta?

Comment: No funciona.. piensa que  Track track1 = new Track(1111, date , "MesuraX", "Pacient1", 12); 

Esta antes que : 

System.out.println("Data??");
    String fechaComoTexto = lector.nextLine();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    date = sdf.parse(fechaComoTexto);
    track1.setDataTrack(date);

Comment: El orden de las sentencias **importa**. No puedes utilizar una variable que no has declarado. En tu caso estás intentando crear tu instancia de `Track` cuando todavía no has declarado ni inicializado `fecha`.

Comment: Pero es la única que me da error.. las otras no.. 

Es decir puedo poner 1111, Mesura... etc. Pero no se que poner para que me lea un Date... es decir si pongo un número me dice que no es un Int, si pongo un texto me dice que no puedo poner un String donde va una Date..

Comment: Por eso ponía todo el código por si había algun error en la forma que lo estaba haciendo.. :(

Comment: Algo me dice que programas con mucho apuro. Detente. Respira. Mira tu código. Básicamente tienes esto: `int a = b; int b = 5;`. El código mostrado previamente **no va a compilar** porque **`b` se declara luego de `a`**. Tiene sentido, ¿cierto? Para arreglarlo, debes declarar e inicializar `b` antes de `a`, de esta manera: `int b = 5; int a = b;`. Lo mismo sucede con tu código. Tienes `new Track(1111, date ...); /*que rayos es date? dice el compilador*/ Date date = sdf.parse(fechaComoTexto);`

Comment: Ese tipo de problemas están fuera del alcance de esta pregunta. Si tienes problemas de ese tipo, creo que sería mejor que revisaras un poco los conceptos más básicos de programación nuevamente. No está mal reforzar ciertos conceptos de vez en cuando, sobretodo cuando se es principiante.

Comment: Respiro.. quizás escribo muy rápido.. Pero sigo teniendo la misma duda.. Es decir el único que me da error es Date y no entiendo el motivo.

Entiendo que dices que tengo que reforzar.. es decir acudo aun foro como este para que me ayude la gente y me explique.

Así que repiro pero sigo con la misma duda.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36431/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-montse-mkd).

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma de realizarlo:

```
String fechaString = "03/01/2016";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy");
Date fecha = df.parse(fechaString);
```

También puedes hacer uso de [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

```
String fechaString = "03/01/2016";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", new Locale("es", "ES"));
Date fecha = df.parse(fechaString);
```